# Changing mySQL Database record value onclick if 0 change to 1

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hi I've built a table for displaying my articles and I'm building it so you can click the star icon and it will make the articled featured (like Joomla's), the part I'm stuck on is I need to check the value of the field in the database and if its 0 then make it 1 and if its 1 make it 0. What would be the simplest method of doing this? The only method I know is by adding the featured value to an id then send that id through ajax and doing an if else statement with my sql statments but I'm already using an id on the element for my article id. Please if anyone could help it would be very much appreciated! Thanks in advance

SQL

```
$sql_articles = "UPDATE `app_articles` SET `art_featured` = 0 WHERE `art_id` =".$_POST['art_id'];
```

Where the 0 is I need it to be 0 or 1 depending on the value it already had

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table SET field = (1 - field)
```

Comment: My problem on is knowing if the value is 0 or 1 ill add my sql statment

Answer (score 0):

If your column holds a single bit, use the negation operator, 1 becomes 0, 0 becomes 1

```
UPDATE MyTable SET A = (~field)
```